# How can I change the color of a DecoratorPanel in GWT?

Tags: java, css, gwt

I see that it uses png images for the rendering, so I am assuming that means I need to provide my own version of these images, with colors changed appropriately.  Where do I put these images, and how do I apply them in the CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so here's the solution.

- Go to the [GWT Theme Generator](http://works.sen-sei.in/gtg/)
- choose the color you want
- choose a name for your style
- click **generate**
- take the jar file it produces, and add it to your classpath
- add a reference to the new style in your app.gwt.xml file

If you're unhappy with using the Theme Generator, or afraid it might disappear one day, just do it once and thereafter hack the contents of the jar file it produces.

Answer (score 1):

You can use he following code to apply your own CSS style for Decorator panel.

```
 DecoratorPanel panel=new DecoratorPanel();
 panel.setStyleName("decorator-panel");
```

In your css file you can apply styles to decorator-panel.Using this we can change colour.For image you create one image directory under public directory(the directory which is having your css file) and put your image there.Then in css you can get image.